# correct type-cast for boost de-serializations of different derived classes

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

In my application, there are agents of different types. I am planning to use boost serialization for sending/receiving data between agents.(by sending/receiving, I actually mean writing/reading operation the serialization target file)

A receiving agent may receive data of different data whose type is not known in advance. Suppose the data format has a general structure like this:

```
class Base
{
 public:
  int message_type_id;
}

class Derived_1
{
 public:
 Derived_1(int message_type_id_):message_type_id(message_type_id_){}
 struct data_1 {...}; 
};


class Derived_2
{
 public:
 Derived_2(int message_type_id_):message_type_id(message_type_id_){}
 struct data_2 {...}; 
};
```

the sending agent can send(i.e serialize) any of the two derived types. Similarly, the receiving agent can receive(i.e de-serialize) any of the two derived types; while what I can see in the [tutorial(Dumping derived classes through base class pointers)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-boostserialization/index.html?ca=drs-) is like this:

```
void save() 
{ 
  std::ofstream file("archive.xml"); //target file
  boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(file); 
  oa.register_type<date>( );// you know what you are sending, so you make proper modifications here to do proper registration
  base* b = new date(15, 8, 1947);
  oa & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(b); 
} 

void load() 
{ 
  std::ifstream file("archive.xml"); //target file
  boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia(file); 
  ia.register_type<date>( );// I don't know which derived class I am receiving, so I can't do a proper registration
  base *dr;
  ia >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(dr); 
  date* dr2 = dynamic_cast<date*> (dr); 
  std::cout << dr2;
}
```

as you can see, `xml_oarchive` and `xml_iarchive` do a `register_type<date>` before serialize/deserialization. so the receiving end will know in advance what to `dynamic_cast` to.
whereas in my case, since I know what I am sending, I can do proper registration&serialization on case-to-case basis. However, on the receiving end, I dont't know in advance what to register and what to dynamic cast.

Is there a way I can tell the type in advance so that the receiving can do a casting?

thanks

**EDIT:**
Here is the simplified modification of [demo.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/example/demo.cpp) I save an object, and then restore it.

```
#include <cstddef> // NULL
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/archive/tmpdir.hpp>

#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/assume_abstract.hpp>

/*
 bus_stop is the base class. 
 bus_stop_corner and bus_stop_destination are derived classes from the above base class.
 bus_route has a container that stores pointer to the above derived classes
 */

class bus_stop
{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    virtual std::string description() const = 0;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & type;
    }
protected:
public:
    std::string type;
    bus_stop(){type = "Base";}
    virtual ~bus_stop(){}
};

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(bus_stop)

class bus_stop_corner : public bus_stop
{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    virtual std::string description() const
    {
        return street1 + " and " + street2;
    }
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        // save/load base class information
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<bus_stop>(*this);
        ar & street1 & street2;
    }

public:
    std::string street1;
    std::string street2;
    bus_stop_corner(){}
    bus_stop_corner(
        const std::string & _s1, const std::string & _s2
    ) :
        street1(_s1), street2(_s2)
    {
        type = "derived_bs_corner";
    }
};

class bus_stop_destination : public bus_stop
{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    virtual std::string description() const
    {
        return name;
    }
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<bus_stop>(*this) & name;
    }
public:
    std::string name;
    bus_stop_destination(){}
    bus_stop_destination(
        const std::string & _name
    ) :
        name(_name)
    {
        type = "derived_bs_destination";
    }
};

class bus_route
{

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    typedef bus_stop * bus_stop_pointer;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar.register_type(static_cast<bus_stop_corner *>(NULL));
        ar.register_type(static_cast<bus_stop_destination *>(NULL));
        ar & stops;
    }
public:
    std::list<bus_stop_pointer> stops;
    bus_route(){}
    void append(bus_stop *_bs)
    {
        stops.insert(stops.end(), _bs);
    }
};

//BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(bus_route, 2)

void save_schedule(const bus_route s, const char * filename){
    // make an archive
    std::ofstream ofs(filename);
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << s;
}

void
restore_schedule(bus_route &s, const char * filename)
{
    // open the archive
    std::ifstream ifs(filename);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
    // restore the schedule from the archive
    ia >> s;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    bus_stop *bs1 = new bus_stop_corner(
        "First St", "Second st"
    );
    bus_stop *bs2 = new bus_stop_destination(
        "myName"
    );

    // make a  routes
    bus_route original_route;
    original_route.append(bs1);
    original_route.append(bs2);

    std::string filename1(boost::archive::tmpdir());
    filename1 += "/demofile1.txt";

    save_schedule(original_route, filename1.c_str());
    bus_route new_route ;

    restore_schedule(new_route, filename1.c_str());
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    std::string filename2(boost::archive::tmpdir());
    filename2 += "/demofile2.txt";
    save_schedule(new_route, filename2.c_str());

    delete bs1;
    delete bs2;
    return 0;
}
```

The old and new objects are not equal coz again saving(serializing) the new object to another file results in a different(empty) content. Can you please let me know how I can fix this code to deserialize the derived classes successfully? many thanks

**EDIT-2**
There is nothing wrong with the above code now(after a small typo was fixed). 
I am answering my own question here coz there is another good approach suggested by someone else.
So the **Answer** to my first question is like this :
As long as you register the derived types in the main serialization function (in the above case: serialize() in bus_route class) everything should be fine.

thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to (de-)serialize `boost::shared_ptr<Base>`. The following code demonstrates it. After deserialization the `pDst` is an instance of the `Derived_1` class. The code complied using an online compiler is available on [this link](http://liveworkspace.org/code/33ZJDX%241).

```
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/assume_abstract.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp>

class Base {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
public:
    Base();
    virtual ~Base();
private:
    template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {}
public:
    virtual bool operator ==(const Base &rh) const = 0;
};

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(Base)
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SHARED_PTR(Base)

Base::Base() {
}

Base::~Base() {
}

class Derived_1 : boost::noncopyable, public Base {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
public:
    int m_iValue;
public:
    Derived_1();
    Derived_1(int iValue);
private:
    template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(Base);
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("value", m_iValue);
    }
public:
    bool operator ==(const Base &rh) const;
};

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SHARED_PTR(Derived_1)

Derived_1::Derived_1() : m_iValue(0) {
}

Derived_1::Derived_1(int iValue) : m_iValue(iValue) {
}

bool Derived_1::operator==(const Base &rh) const {
    const Derived_1 *pRH = dynamic_cast<const Derived_1 *>(&rh);
    return pRH != nullptr && pRH->m_iValue == this->m_iValue;
}

#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>

#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(Base, "base")
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(Derived_1, "derived_1")

void test(void) {
    std::string str;
    boost::shared_ptr<Base> pSrc = boost::make_shared<Derived_1>(10);
    boost::shared_ptr<Base> pDst;
    {
        std::ostringstream ofs;
        boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << boost::serialization::make_nvp("item", pSrc);
        str = ofs.str();
    }
    {
        std::istringstream ifs(str);
        boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("item", pDst);
    }
    if (*pSrc == *pDst) {
        printf("Success\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Fail\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    test();
}
```

Comment: @meabyte1024 thanks for your nice answer. But, being a beginner in serialization, I don't understand how using the XML and shared<> version help solving the issue. I think having more than one type of derived class wont change the correct result. How is it working without even registering the derived classes?

Comment: @rahman, let's clarify what the issue is. As soon as I understood, you need to deserialize derived classes, does not matter either it is `Derived_1` or `Derived_2`. Is it correct? If yes, then my example demonstrates it. The deserialization part of the `test` function works with an instance of the `boost::shared_ptr<Base>` class (`pDst`) and the serialization creates the correct derived class instance. The program outputs `Success`. About the 2nd question, there is a hidden registration in the `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID` macro.

Comment: the answer to your question is yes. Your comment also clarifies some of my problems. Still, for the sake of clarifying the concept, could you please let me know what is wrong with my example? (the last code snippet).

Comment: @rahman, the last code snippet's problem is in the `restore_schedule` function. Should I help you or you will find the problem by yourself?

Comment: yes by all means. I knew that function is the source of the problem but I don't know how to do that. While answering the question, please dont remove your first answer coz that is also valid and more optimized. thanks

Comment: any updates yet? BTW, I added a second derived class to your program and tested it. it works just fine. I am marking your answeras true. In the mean time, if you could find a solution to my last code snippet, it would be great. thanks

Comment: To fix the last your issue is necessary to add the `&` between the `bus_route` and `s` words in the `restore_schedule(bus_route s, const char * filename)` line, i.e. it should look like `restore_schedule(bus_route &s, const char * filename)`.

Comment: oh man! oh! honest mistake. Thanks. So we can conclude that as long as we register the correct derived classes in the main serialization function (i.e in bus_rout class), everything should be fine. Thanks for all the help megabyte.